# remove 4th, 5th, 6th position in a string in the sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field which has values like `Activity_ID = AHR265A06AH , AHR265A48AHTEST`

I have to remove 4th ,5th , 6th position in the string.

Here is what i tried and i believe this is not a clean way of writing query.
Can any one guide me in the correct direction.
But my query got i need to in my output.

```
SUBSTRING(ACTIVITY_ID ,1,3) + RIGHT(ACTIVITY_ID, LEN(ACTIVITY_ID) - 6) AS ActivityLookup
```

**INPUT**:

> Activity_ID
>
> AHR265A06AH
>
> AHR265A48AHTEST

**OUTPUT**

> Activity_ID
>
> AHRA06AH
>
> AHRA48AHTEST

Comment: Why do you think your solution isn't valid or the best approach? It works perfectly well for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you looking for alternate way?

Comment: Note: substring(1, 3) is functionally the same as left(3), but really there's not an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Never **never** _**NEVER**_ store csv data in a column!

Comment: @Martin Parkin - I thought there can be a better to write the query..Yeah it works perfectly fine but i am  trying to learn if there are any other ways that i can write the query in the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `STUFF()` function: [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188043.aspx/)
.

Start from Character 4, and replace 3 characters with nothing;

```
STUFF(ACTIVITY_ID,4,3,'') AS ActivityLookup
```